# How to change the text in my Textblock in MainWindow using iCommand?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

[image]

Basically I have one textblock and 2 button, I want the textblock Text to change according to the button I click. For example, if I click on the Button 1, it will display, "Button 1 is click"

if I click on button 2, it will display "Button 2 is click"

This is my ViewModel

```
namespace ICommandProject2.ViewModel
{

    class ViewModel
    {
        public ICommand myCommand { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            myCommand = new myCommand(ExecutedMethod);
        }

        private void ExecutedMethod (object parameter)
        {
            MainWindow m = new MainWindow();
            m.txtBlock.Text = "Button 1 is click";
        }


    }
}
```

This my Command Class

namespace ICommandProject2.Command

```
{

    class myCommand : ICommand
    {

        Action<object> actionExecuted;

        public myCommand(Action<object> ExecutedMethod)
        {
            actionExecuted = ExecutedMethod;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            actionExecuted(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Mainwindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ICommandProject2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ICommandProject2.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ViewModel x:Key="vm"/>

    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnOne" Content="Button 1" Command="{Binding myCommand, Source={StaticResource vm}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="273,232,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" FontSize="18"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="273,89,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is a textblock" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnTwo" Content="Button 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="495,232,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" FontSize="18" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I click on the button, nothing is happening, what should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use binding to set TextBlock text.

create a property fro binding in a view model and change that property in command handler:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand myCommand { get; set; }

    private string _title = "This is a textblock";
    public string Title { get { return _title; } }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        myCommand = new myCommand(ExecutedMethod);
    }

    private void ExecutedMethod (object parameter)
    {
        _title = "Button 1 was clicked";
        OnPropertyChanged("Title");
    }
}
```

I omitted that part, but you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify view about changes in a view model.

use Binding in a view:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock" Text="{Binding Title}" ...
```

(command as it is now doesn't work becuase it creates an new instance of Window (`MainWindow m = new MainWindow();`) instead of working with open Window)